# flutter test: Run | Debug | Profile button runs Gradle task and does not run the unit test

Tags: flutter

I am writing unit test for my flutter application but could not run the unit test with the `Run | Debug | Profile` button above the `main()` function of the test file.

I have the test file as follow:

```
void main() {
  late HttpServiceBase httpServicBase;

  setUpAll(() {
    httpServicBase = HttpServiceBase();
  });

  group("get", () {
    test("given empty url, should throw exception", () {
        // some test code
    });
  });
}
```

I can see the `Run | Debug | Profile` button above the `main` function.

However, when I click the `Debug` button, I get the following error

```
Build file 'D:\FlutterApp\android\app\build.gradle' line: 90

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Parameter specified as non-null is null: method com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BaseFlavor.resValue, parameter value

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

However, when I run `flutter test .\tests\unit_tests\libs\services\http_service_test.dart`, the test runs as expected.

I don't have specific setup so I don't know what could be wrong.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Rename the folder from `tests` to `test` solves the problem.